# In Pandas, is there a way to assign values based on data range?

Tags: python, pandas

I will try to describe my challenge as much as possible. I have a table like this:

```
ID  |  PHASE  |  code    |      START       |  END 
A      SSH        SLP           01/02/2020  | 02/02/2020
A      SSH        DRL           02/02/2020  | 02/20/2020
A      SSH        TYU           01/03/2020  | 01/30/2020
A      SSH        TYT           01/04/2020  | 01/30/2020
A      MNH        TOH           01/15/2020  | 02/01/2020
A      MNH        DRL           02/05/2020  | 03/01/2020
A      MNH        TYU           01/16/2020  | 02/02/2020
A      MNH        TYT           01/19/2020  | 02/01/2020
A      SRF        RIC           02/10/2020  | 03/01/2020
A      SRF        DRL           02/19/2020  | 03/10/2020
A      SRF        TYU           02/13/2020  | 03/05/2020
A      SRF        TYT           02/11/2020  | 03/01/2020
(to E)
```

ID element goes all the way to E with the exact same PHASE, I was required to get the min date for each of the phases where "code" not equal to "DRL", i accomplished it doing this:

```
phase_value = {'SSH': (1,2,3),
           'SRF': (4,5,6),
           'INT': (7,8,9),
           'MNH': (13,14,15)}

 for key in phase_value.keys():

        merge_table.loc[merge_table[ ((merge_table['Phase']==key) & (merge_table['Actual Operation']!='DRL'))].groupby('WELL_ID')['Start'].idxmin(), "test"] = phase_value[key][0]
        merge_table.loc[merge_table[ ((merge_table['Phase']==key) & (merge_table['Actual Operation']=='DRL'))].groupby('WELL_ID')['Start'].idxmin(), "test"] = phase_value[key][1]
        merge_table.loc[merge_table[ ((merge_table['Phase']==key) & (merge_table['Actual Operation']=='DRL'))].groupby('WELL_ID')['End'].idxmax(), "test"] = phase_value[key][2]
```

so for each value in a dic find the min and assign a value based on the phase code, for each of the ID,i am sure there are better ways to do it but that worked for me.

```
ID  |  PHASE  |  code    |      START       |  END         |   test
A      SSH        SLP           01/02/2020  | 02/02/2020        1
A      SSH        DRL           02/02/2020  | 02/20/2020        2
A      SSH        TYU           01/03/2020  | 01/30/2020
A      SSH        TYT           01/04/2020  | 01/30/2020
A      MNH        TOH           01/15/2020  | 02/01/2020        13
A      MNH        DRL           02/05/2020  | 03/01/2020        14
A      MNH        TYU           01/16/2020  | 02/02/2020
A      MNH        TYT           01/19/2020  | 02/01/2020
A      SRF        RIC           02/10/2020  | 03/01/2020        4
A      SRF        DRL           02/19/2020  | 03/10/2020        5
A      SRF        TYU           02/13/2020  | 03/05/2020
A      SRF        TYT           02/11/2020  | 03/01/2020
(to E)
```

if i would like to add for example for Phase SSH, the number 1 if the Start date > than the min but < of the value 2 which is PHASE == 'SSH' and "code" == "DRL" but for each of the ID's and for each of the PHASE.

Really hope i made myself clear on this. Thanks in advance.

expected:

```
ID  |  PHASE  |  code    |      START       |  END         |   test
A      SSH        SLP           01/02/2020  | 02/02/2020        1
A      SSH        DRL           02/02/2020  | 02/20/2020        2
A      SSH        TYU           01/03/2020  | 01/30/2020        1
A      SSH        TYT           01/04/2020  | 01/30/2020        1
A      MNH        TOH           01/15/2020  | 02/01/2020        13
A      MNH        DRL           02/05/2020  | 03/01/2020        14
A      MNH        TYU           01/16/2020  | 02/02/2020
A      MNH        TYT           01/19/2020  | 02/01/2020
A      SRF        RIC           02/10/2020  | 03/01/2020        4
A      SRF        DRL           02/19/2020  | 03/10/2020        5
A      SRF        TYU           02/13/2020  | 03/05/2020
A      SRF        TYT           02/11/2020  | 03/01/2020
(to E)
```

Comment: `Start date > than the min but < of the value 2` which `min` and which `value 2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang correct, however i am having problems with the syntax, like:  merge_table.loc[merge_table[ ((merge_table['Phase']==key) & (merge_table['Actual Operation']!='DRL'))].groupby('WELL_ID')['Start'].min(), "test"] ---- this gives the min value but for each of the ID's, now how in the same line find the other value and assign the #1. thats where i am having a lot of issues.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to identify the min value in `START` and max value in `END` for each `ID` and `Phase`. Then assign the corresponding value from `phase_value` dict? By doing so, you only need 2 values in each of `phase_value`?

Comment: yes correct i tried setting 2 conditions, one to get the min value for each of the ID's, then second condition to find the min value in start where code = drl, then i merge both and got a table with well_id, start_x and start_y, the problem is i will have to loop it all and fill out the ranges which i believe is not a good way to solve the issue.